# How to open APK file and install?

Tags: android, react-native

My code:

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

const downloadDest = `${RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath}/${(Math.random() * 1000) | 0}.apk`;
const options = {
    fromUrl: url,
    toFile: downloadDest,
    background: true,
};
RNFS.downloadFile().promise.then(res => {
  // How to open APK file and install?
})
```

How do I open an APK file and install it?

I have tried using `Linking.openURL (downloadDest)` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `rn-fetch-blob` instead of `react-native-fs`. add the following `RFFectchBlob.config`, after the APK download finish, it will auto-install for android,

```
const android = RNFetchBlob.android;
RNFetchBlob.config({
      appendExt : 'apk',
      timeout:180000, 
      addAndroidDownloads : {
        notification : true,
        useDownloadManager : true,
        mime : 'application/vnd.android.package-archive',
        mediaScannable : true,
        title:"",
        description : '',
        path: "your apk download path"
    }
    })
      .fetch("GET", downloadUrl)
      .then(res => {
        if(res.respInfo.timeout){
          Linking.openURL(downloadUrl)
          return;
        }
        android.actionViewIntent(res.path(), 'application/vnd.android.package-archive')
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        Linking.openURL(downloadUrl)
      });
```

or use the *hieuxit* answer to define a native module to open the APK

Comment: `'android' is not defined.`     `android.actionViewIntent()`

Comment: @ebyteebyte; I add it.

Comment: @ebyteebyte, if you think the answer is good and helps you, you can also upvote the answer.

Comment: But it's strange, the Android emulator runs normally, but the installation interface cannot pop up on the Android phone (Android v8.1)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59211785/rn-fetch-blob-actionviewintent-does-not-work-on-android-8-1-phones

Comment: for Android 8.0, you have to check if it has permission. I will answer in your question.

Comment: Thank you, it's because of permissions

Answer (score 0):

For native android code, you should send an intent to install the APK like code below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

You use react native, so you can write a native module and expose the API to call. Or easier use the library named "react-native-send-intent"

https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-send-intent#example--install-a-remote-apk

Comment: `react-native-send-intent` Does he have a download progress?

Comment: Nope, react-native-send-intent is a library to send an intent from react-native code (js code) for Android. It's not the File Download library like rn-fetch-blob or react-native-fs